# What's an entropy measure for the sequence $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...$?

Tags: entropy

I'm puzzled by the measure $$E(S) = -\sum p(i) \lg p(i)$$ because I'm considering a source emitting $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...$ and having the maximum entropy as given by $E(S)$.  Shouldn't $E(S)$ measure the quantity of information?  The sequence that just repeats $1$ after $0$ seems to me to convey very little information --- contained in this very phrase.

Where am I wrong in my understanding of entropy and of $E(S)$?

Comment: What is the connection to cryptography? This appears to be a question that is better suited for the [computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: there are different definitions for entropy, in this case, you can rewrite that is 0,1,repeat, so, for cryptographic definitions of entropy, 2 bytes maybe?

Comment: Entropy (in the sense of the definition you give) is a property of probability distributions; it makes no sense to speak of the entropy of a sequence.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to *measure* entropy. All empirical notions of entropy require some assumption about your random source.

Comment: @yyyyyyy Why can it not be measures objectively? For example the size of the smallest algorithm (including data) on a given Turing Complete machine that can output the original data? (that would be a few bytes in this case)

Comment: You are probably asking about the **complexity** of that sequence. The sequence itself has no entropy, and wouldn't even if it were perfectly random. The generation method, however, can exhibit entropy and that entropy is measured as the binary logarithm of the number of possible states the algorithm can be in.

Comment: @RocketNuts A byte is 8 bits. Surely you don't mean two _bytes_?

Comment: @EllaRose, see, for example, [NIST SP 800-90B](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-90b/final) which makes recommendation for entropy sources in random bit generators, which are important for key generation in many cryptosystems.  In the document, NIST uses a measure of entropy called min-entropy, a conservative measure.  I'm looking here at another way to measure entropy --- or so I think.

Comment: @fkraiem, so you're saying $E(S)$ has no connection to, say, min-entropy as defined in [NIST SP 800-90B](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90B.pdf)?

Comment: @forest A few bytes, yes. For example in x86 assembler (i.e. any intel processor) it would be `mov ax,1; @A: stosw; jmp @A` which is like 5 bytes or so. But of course it can be much smaller on a suitable Turing Complete machine that operates on bit level.

Comment: @user45491 We know that entropy is relevant to cryptography, but your question appears to have no connection to cryptography as it is asked. If your question were something like "NIST SP800-90B talks about entropy measurement, ...insert question..." then there would be a clear connection to cryptography. As your question is written, there is no such connection.

Comment: @RocketNuts `For example the size of the smallest algorithm (including data) on a given Turing Complete machine that can output the original data` sounds almost exactly like the definition of [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), which is not entropy (as forest indicated).

Comment: @EllaRose Right, yes, it's pretty much the Kolmogorov complexity. Roughly speaking I would interpret both 'entropy' as well as 'Kolmogorov complexity' as some sort of measurement of the true amount of information in a piece of data. Or perhaps the 'information density'. But maybe I am mistaken about the definitions here. What do you call or how do you define the _entropy_ of a data stream?

Comment: @RocketNuts As [previously stated by fkraiem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67058/whats-an-entropy-measure-for-the-sequence-0-1-0-1-0-1?noredirect=1#comment148078_67058), entropy is not a characteristic of a data stream, it is a characteristic of the probability distribution that the data stream was generated by. A data stream has no entropy, the process that generates it does.

Comment: @EllaRose OK, so what if we take the smallest algorithm (following the Kolmogorov complexity definition) and consider that as the process that generates it. What would be the entropy of that?

Comment: @RocketNuts Zero, because it can only generate that one stream. If you had an algorithm that could output either 1010101... or 111111... and you have no way to predict which stream will be output with greater than 50% accuracy, then it would have one bit of entropy.

Comment: @forest So entropy has to do with (un)predictability? Could one say that entropy is measure of possible variation in the output of a process? Or the inverse of the likelihood of guessing its output? 
If I have four processes: A is a coin toss (produces a random 1 or 0) and B is a dice roll (produces a random number 1 to 6). And C and D repetitively do A and B, i.e. C produces a random stream of 1s and 0s, and D procudes a random stream of numbers 1-6. Can I say the entropy of A is 1 bit, and that of B is $^2$log(6)≈2.58 bits? And what about C and D, both infinite entropy?

Comment: @forest Now that I think of it, isn't the entropy of _any_ algorithm always zero? Because an algoritm is, by definition, always deterministic. You cannot have an algorithm that produces either 10101… or 11111… So for anything to have any entropy at all, would require a physical source of true randomness. And we aren't even sure if the universe is non-deterministic i.e. if true randomness exists at all. It's fundamentally unpredictable for us, but not necessarily non-deterministic, as we can't be sure if there are hidden variables to which Einstein referred as "God doesn't play dice".

Comment: @RocketNuts Zero entropy is if the algorithm has only one possible output. One bit of entropy is if it has two possible outputs. A CSPRNG like ChaCha20 has 256 bits of entropy because it can output $2^{256}$ distinct streams. A stream of data itself doesn't have entropy (despite people commonly describing the "entropy" of data). So for a coin flip, it's the _coin flip_ itself that has entropy, not the result of the coin flip.

Comment: I now understand the difference between entropy of a process and complexity or data density of stream, thanks. But regarding your example: ChaCha20 is a deterministic algorithm. Given a certain input, it can produce only *one* output stream (which depends on the input). It's a **pseudo** RNG after all, not an actual RNG. So isn't the entropy in this case determined by the process that generates the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's just fill it in! Your generator has two possible outcomes, both with certain probabilities. For the every element of your sequence, you're *certain about its outcome*, thus:

\begin{align*}
E(S)&=-p_0\log p_0 - p_1\log p_1\\
    &=-p_0\log p_0 - (1-p_0)\log (1-p_0)\\
    &\mathrel{\mathop{=}_{p_0\to1}} -1\log 1 - 0\\
    &=-1\cdot0=0
\end{align*}

Seems like your source does not convey *any* information (zero bits), because indeed you already know what it will produce! Talking about entropy of a source only makes sense when the source has a stochastic behaviour; when it has an element of unpredictability.

Comment: Your computation doesn't follow.  The probability of getting a $0$ is $1/2$ and of getting a $1$ is also $1/2$.  So $E(S) = -1/2 \lg (1/2) -1/2 \lg(1/2) = 1/2 + 1/2 = 1$.

Comment: @user45491 No, at any position in the produced stream one of the values has probablity 1 and the other has probability 0.

Comment: @user45491: think of it this way. At any position in the stream, I ask you to guess the next symbol. The probability *with which you will succeed* is the probability we're talking about. We're not talking about "how many symbols on average".

Comment: Interesting.  I don't seem to agree.  What's the probability of getting a zero given no other information?  I say it's $1/2$.  What's the probability of getting a zero given a one was just produced by the source? I say it's $1$.  The formula $E(S)$ uses $p_i$ where $p_i$ is the proportion of symbol $i$ in the source.  What do you say?

Comment: (maybe we should move this to chat). Given no other information, you don't have the sequence you posed any more. It would mean that your source has *two* possible outcomes: $0,1,0,1,\dots$ and $1,0,1,0,\dots$. That would mean your source has exactly *one* bit of information, because you can distinguish two outputs.

Comment: @user45491 Welcome to entropy.  It's pretty much an open question how to calculate it for a complex sequence. The Shannon log formula is pretty difficult to use as determining $i$ is well neigh impossible. That's why you're finding that  $p("1") = \frac{1}{2}$, yet $p("01") = 1$ and that all the answers are different.

Comment: @PaulUszak It is not an open question. For a complex sentence, the amount of entropy is exactly zero. As we've all told you countless times, entropy is something used to describe _possibilities_, how complexity. Any discrete information has exactly zero bits of entropy.

Comment: @user45491, indeed, given that a one was just produced, the probability is one. And that's what I computed in my answer! The result becomes 0 bits of information.

Comment: @user45491 Paul has been a problem on this website for a long time. We can't educate him and we can't ban him. I recommend ignoring him.